# How to solve a non-linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find the solution of the equation: $$(2e^y-t) \dot{y} = 1$$ with the initial value $y(0)=0$

Here's what I tried:
I tried to separate y and t - didn't work.
I tried to denote $x=2e^y$ and solve the system $\cases{{\dot x = 2e^y}\\{\dot{y} = \frac{1}{\dot{x}-t\dot{y}}}}$ and again.. nothing.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your equation can be written as

$$2e^y \dot{y}-t \dot{y}-1=0.$$
Multiply both sides by $e^y>0$ to get

$$2e^{2y} \dot{y}-te^y \dot{y}-e^y=0 $$

or

$$\frac{d}{dt} \left(e^{2y}-te^y \right)=0,$$
which can be integrated to

$$e^{2y}-te^{y}-c/4=0 $$

so that

$$e^y=\frac{t \pm \sqrt{t^2-4 \cdot 1 \cdot (-c/4)}}{2}=\frac{t \pm \sqrt{t^2+c}}{2}.$$

Finally

$y(t)= \log \left( \frac{t \pm \sqrt{t^2+c}}{2} \right)$, and using the initial value we get

$$0= \log \left( \pm \sqrt{c}/2 \right). $$

Hence, $c=4$ and the plus sign must be taken.